# IE File->Send->Page by E-Mail Hide elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, internet-explorer

From client side, client opens web page, then goes to File->Send->Page by E-mail. Client Browser executes a Page.IsPostBack set to "False". The question is:
Is there a way using CSS to hide elements like SiteMap, etc from showing in the e-mail body. I  have looked at CSS @media , but could not find an option besides "screen". If there is not an option using CSS, is there a way to identify the Request type so that elements can be modified using CSS?.

Any ideas, in how best to deal with this?. I will really appreciate it.

Although it seems related to the question "Sending contents of a particular div", because we are trying to send the whole web page except heading and other elements, we are not interested in clicking a button in the page to send e-mail since it does not resolve the hiding of elements when in IE client goes to File->Send->page by e-mail.

Comment: "but could not find an option besides screen". That's surprising, considering [the specification calls out a specific list of recognized types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types), which I found by simply searching for "CSS @media"...

Comment: yes there are types,,, which applies when page is being embeded in the body of an e-mail at the client who might be using for example Outlook?

Comment: Mike McCaughan, by the way, Thanks I am going over and reading the link you provided. I haven't found a type so far that would apply.

Comment: Well, I just made a comment, not an answer, because I don't know an answer :). You might try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406603/sending-contents-of-a-particular-div-on-page-with-send-page-by-e-mail-option-o or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266887/how-does-the-send-page-by-email-feature-in-internet-explorer-choose-to-send-as

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had read both questions, no luck with either. I am impress there seems to be no way to specify the css media type or css display option when the page is displayed outside the browser. I found Required Field Validators have a Display="Dynamic" which hides them in the email body. I found this: http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/client-specific-styles/   makes ref to .ExternalClass for Outlook. But so far not an answer yet.  I do not want to place a button to send the page, because the problem will still be unresolved, if anyone clicks the File->Send->Page by E-mail.